# How to show bootstrap pop up then hide after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bootstrap-modal

I want to show bootstrap pop up on page load and I want to hide this popup after 3 seconds. I found the example on google but don't know how to implement this code according to my requirements.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in jquery with setTimeout. you can put onload function to body and call `onload="openModal()"`

```js
function openModal(){
    $("#exampleModalLong").modal();
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#exampleModalLong").modal("hide"); }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<body onload="openModal()">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openModal()" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Brother its working but no onload i dont want to button click for showing pop up please tell me how can  i do tthis .

Comment: Do you want to open modal without clicking when page loaded ? I edited answer check it

Answer (score -1):

Yes, here's a method using CSS

```
    html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#exampleModalLong {
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 3s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 3s forwards;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 3s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 3s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
```

Here's the working example https://jsfiddle.net/xcLj9hfo/